# One to Many Entity framework Update

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a scenario that I have a registration form with employee details. Among this data I am saving the employee contacts in a different table called as ContactMaster and rest of the data is saving in EmployeeMaster. I have a foreign key inside EmployeeMaster as ContactId. How can I update my registration form using entity framework. My class entity classes as follows.

```
public partial class ContactMaster
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public ContactMaster()
        {
            this.BranchMasters = new HashSet<BranchMaster>();
            this.EmployeeMasters = new HashSet<EmployeeMaster>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string TelephoneNumber1 { get; set; }
        public string TelephoneNumber2 { get; set; }
        public string Mobilenumber1 { get; set; }
        public string MobileNumber2 { get; set; }
        public string EmailId { get; set; }
        public string FaxNumber1 { get; set; }
        public string FaxNumber2 { get; set; }
        public string WebSite { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<EmployeeMaster> EmployeeMasters { get; set; }
    }
```

and EmployeeMaster as follows.

```
 public partial class EmployeeMaster
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int BranchId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public string Firstname { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
        public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
        public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
        public string AddressLine3 { get; set; }
        public string Town { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }
        public int ContactId { get; set; }
        public string PassportNumber { get; set; }
        public string PassportIssuedCountry { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime PassportExpiryDate { get; set; }
        public string VisaNumber { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> VisaExpiryDate { get; set; }
        public int JobRoleId { get; set; }
        public int BandId { get; set; }
        public string ChargeValue { get; set; }
        public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
        public int StatusId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> IsDeleted { get; set; }


        public virtual ContactMaster ContactMaster { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "How can I update my registration form using entity framework"? The title of the question seems to suggest you want change the code to have a many to many model. The question stated though seems to ask how you can update your html form.

Comment: track them, and set the collections/the navigation property how you want. with EF's help, you shouldn't really have to take care of your FK values.

Comment: Then what id the option? DO we have to go for Stored Procedures?